# Ajax call not working out in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I referred to some examples online and modified functions.php and the front end template to fire an ajax call to fetch some data. But I've hard time understanding on hoe the data is returned from the requested url.

At the end of functions.php, I added,

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
function myFunction(){
    echo "hi";
   die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myFunction');
```

In my custom template page, I added,

```
var datavalue = 'test data string';

  jQuery.ajax({

      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: { 'datavar' : datavalue }

  }).success(function(data) {

      console.log("successfully run ajax request..." + data);

  }).done(function(){

      console.log("I am from done function");

  }).fail(function(){

      console.log("I am from fail function.");

  }).always(function(){

      console.log("I am from always function");

  });

});
```

After running it, I get these response.

```
I am from fail function.  
I am from always function
```

I don't understand how to fetch data from a specific url and display the result in ajax's success function.

I don't even know how the function defined in function.php would be called by this ajax call? How are they related?

Please explain. Also I would like to fire ajax call to query database by passing keyword, how can I do that in wordpress?

Comment: Check your network tab for the result of the AJAX request to find out why the request failed. Request should succeed regardless of the action being defined in WordPress properly or not. Did the request reach the correct location? Does the JavaScript code contains error?

Comment: the request is made to the specified url however there's error 500.

Comment: There you go. Please find out why did the server return an error instead. Without error messages / log, it'll only be a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX function should include an action parameter to tell admin-ajax which function you would like to execute.

```
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  method: "GET",
  data: {
        action : 'myFunction'
  }
```

(or, if you are set up for it, then you can include it in your url, as below)

```
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=myFunction"
```

Also, your function in functions.php should be written in PHP:

```
function myFunction(){
    echo 'hello';
    die();
}
```

Comment: I tried addign action parameter in the url and also tried adding it inside data but still not getting response from success function

Comment: Have you written your function in valid php?

Comment: yes, i did notice my  mistake and corrected by writing valid php there..but the server still returns 500 error

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a action on ajax like.

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: {
            action : 'myFunction'
           'datavar' : datavalue,
       }
  });
```

PHP function need to edit.

```
function myFunction(){
    echo 'success calling functions';
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: I added action but still getting response from fail function instead of success

Comment: yes, i wrote a valid  function, do check my edited post

Comment: I have added php sample function.

Comment: the myFunction is not invoked

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the "action" parameter in "data". Which contains callback function's name. Please check the attached link.
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/

In this you've to make a callback functions. 
Wordpress dsnt work with the specific url.

But if you still want to use the specific url. Follow the steps:-
1. Make a wordpress template.
2. Add your specific url code there.
3. Make a page in the admin panel and assign the template you've created above.
4. Now the permalink of that page can be used as a specific url in the jQuery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers, in your `function.php`, make use of `$_REQUEST`. The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via AJAX from the Javascript call. Something like this

```
function myFunction() {

    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
{
    global $wpdb;
    $keyword = $_REQUEST["keyword"];
    
    if($keyword){
       
        $query = "
        SELECT `$keyword`, COUNT($keyword) AS Total 
        FROM `profileinfo` GROUP BY `$keyword`
        ";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        $data = array();

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row
        }
    
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
    }
     die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myFunction');
```